# jQuery $(this).data return undefined inside select

Tags: jquery

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Rg8rf/

```
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).data('value');
    alert(src);
});
```

How do I grab a value from `data-value`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this in that case means the select list, so you have to catch the selected value inside "this". This will work for you:

```
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).children(":selected").data('value');
    alert(src);
});​
```

Its very easy to test in this cases if you are not sure and don't get the value of what you expected. Inside the change method you could just write console.debug(this) and look in the console to see whats inside, or just alert($(this).attr("id"))

Answer (score 2):

if you want to grab value of label just

```
    $("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).find("option");
    src.each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
    });
});
```

look this for the demo http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/ZhGt3/5/

use function `.html()` to get value for tag like this `<element> value </element>`,if anothe case `<element> <div>test</div> <element>`, you can customize with selector jquery...but make sure element has been have method what do you want to use.

Comment: I think input elements,select etc wont support html(),you have to use text() or val()

Comment: no that is supported, you can see in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/ZhGt3/3/ please recorect your minus on my answer.

Comment: How ever i upvoted..html method will get all the option values with in that..i think thats not what he wants

Comment: yes, i have fork him jsfiddle and you can see the demo in http://jsfiddle.net/viyancs/ZhGt3/5/

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(this).children('option:selected').attr('data-value');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).val(); //for value
    alert(src);
});
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); //for the text
    alert(src);
});
```

For any other params

```
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-value'); //for other params
    alert(src);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-value');
```

`.data()` has nothing to do with it. leave the innocent alone :D

Comment: .data("value") is a shortcut for the **data-** prefix so it would work just fine. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 1):

It's not working cause $(this) refers to the #label not the selected option.

```
$("#label").on('change', function() {
    var src = $('option:selected').data('value');
    alert(src);
});​
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AAugX/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#label").change(function() {
    var src = $(this).find('option:selected').data('value);
    alert(src);
});
```

I modified your fiddle accordingly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Rg8rf/1/

Answer (score 1):

var src = $(this).find('option:selected').data('value');

without attr